# try and error except catch break?

Tags: python, file, break

I am trying to write the code so that i eliminate the duplicate in my result file, which is the line with "N/A" and line underneath it. Here is what i have:

```
    with open('false_'+uniprotID+'.txt','w') as fileinput:        
        for index, (start, end) in enumerate(searchPFAM(fname)):       
            for item in lookup[uniprotID]:
                for names in wholelookup[uniprotID]:
                    if re.search(r'\d+',names).group(0)==item and start <= int(item) <= end:
                        result = str(int(item) - start + 1)
                        try:
                            fileinput.write(">{0} | at position {1} | start= {2}, end= {3} | description: {4}\n".format(uniprotID, result, start, end, names))
                            fileinput.write(''.join(makeList[start-1:end]))
                            textwrap.wrap(''.join(makeList[start-1:end]),width = 60)
                            fileinput.write('\n')
                        except ErrorIO as e:
                           break 
                    else:
                        fileinput.write(">{0} | N/A | start= {1}, end= {2} | description: {3} \n".format(uniprotID, start, end, names))
                        fileinput.write(''.join(makeList[start-1:end]))
                        textwrap.wrap(''.join(makeList[start-1:end]),width = 60)
                        fileinput.write('\n')
```

My result file look like this:

> Q14591 | at position 4 | start= 174, end= 196 | description: A177T
>
> YQCRHCSKSFSQRSDLVKHQRIH
>
> Q14591 | N/A | start= 174, end= 196 | description: M418T
>
> YQCRHCSKSFSQRSDLVKHQRIH
>
> Q14591 | at position 21 | start= 398, end= 420 | description: M418T
>   YACSDCTKSFSRRSDLVKHQRIH
>
> Q14591 | N/A | start= 398, end= 420 | description: M418T
>
> YACSDCTKSFSRRSDLVKHQRIH

Comment: Are you expecting the code in the the `try:` block to raise any particular error? If not, `try/except` is probably not the way to deal with you duplicates.

Comment: @Marius what other ways i should deal with this? do you have any suggestion? thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm not at all sure what makes you unhappy about this code...

Comment: @NedBatchelder in my result file.. i have duplicate lines. as you can see line 3 and 4 is same as line 1-2 except the N/A in line 3. So i am trying to get ride of line 3-4 and line 7-8

Comment: @ChadD: I don't think you've shown us enough code. There's logic in `searchPFAM` and data in `lookup` and `wholelookup` that have an effect here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just filter them out afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Take the four lines of code you have duplicated, and create a function from them.  Then invoke the function from both places.  You'll have to parameterize the differences, that is, make an argument than can be given the different values for the differences between the two invocations.

For example:

```
def do_the_common_thing(fileinput, uniprotID, result, start, end, names):
    fileinput.write(">{0} | {1} | start= {2}, end= {3} | description: {4}\n".format(uniprotID, result, start, end, names))
    fileinput.write(''.join(makeList[start-1:end]))
    textwrap.wrap(''.join(makeList[start-1:end]),width = 60)
    fileinput.write('\n')
```

This is a lot of arguments, you might be able to come up with a better refactoring.

Comment: doing this won't make any difference though.. does it? i m not sure

Comment: Sorry, I thought the "duplicate" you were trying to remove was the duplicated code.  This won't help with your problem, but it is a good idea anyway... :)

Comment: No i meant the duplicate in the result file